# C++ библиотека Math.h: как найти функцию в исходном коде?

Tags: c++, математика

У меня есть задание - разобрать функции sin cos в библиотеке math. Когда я открывал [исходники](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/math_8h_source.html), я надеялся увидеть там просто две функции, которые мне нужно будет описать. Но, вместо этого нашел только несколько строчек, которые ничего мне толком так и не сказали. Вообще, есть ли эти функции в читаемом виде и как до них добраться?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Их там не будет. Это библиотечные функции. В данном случае лучше скомпилировать и посмотреть, что там.

В случае с линуском - синус будет скорее всего в glibc. И исходники можно [посмотреть](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284860/how-does-c-compute-sin-and-other-math-functions).

В случае различных встраиваемых систем, может быть просто табличка.

- [посмотреть реализацию в freebsd](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/lib/msun/src/k_sin.c?rev=1.11;content-type=text%2Fplain).
- Но и сам процессор может вычислять командой [fcos](http://www.club155.ru/x86cmdfpu/FCOS).

Comment: @KoVadim есть же архитектуры, где нет команды fcos. Те же 8-бит микроконтроллеры, например. Взять исходники оттуда и смотреть, сколько глаз хватит.

Comment: Спасибо, я думаю мне будет достаточно реализации в glibc.
Правда, с виду, там черт ногу сломит.

Comment: @alexlz - я не утверждал, что компилятор обязательно будет использовать ассемблерные команды. Скорее нет, так как они в свое время были достаточно медленные. А по всем приведены мной ссылкам есть исходники.

Да, и не нужно забывать о простой формуле, что синус в квадрате+косинус в квадрате равен 1. Это помогает в некоторых случаях быстрее вычислять.

Comment: @KoVadim по ссылкам глядеть поленился. А квадрат из единички вычитать -- это имеет смысл, если нужны одновременно синус и косинус одного угла. 

В микроконтроллерах (старых) зачастую просто хранят табличные значения с некоторым шагом и точности для их нужд хватает. (Или можно разложить угол на сумму известного и неизвестного, а синус небольшого угла приблизительно равен самому углу...)

Comment: По ссылкам не ходил, но критикую. Как это замечательно!

Comment: Да это не столько критика, сколько информация о дополнительных вариантах. Продираться через кучу ответов на stackoverflow.com ...